# Craft criteria for asset folders

Tags: plugin-development, craft3, assets

In my plugin, I would like to search a folder.
However, I cannot find any information about the criteria for folders.
Are there any documentation or something?

```
$n = Craft::$app->assets->findFolder(array(
    'name' => $folder,
    'parent' => $p_folder
));
```

My code is like this. Folder name is not unique, so I have to also use its parent.
However, I do not know how to include parent folder in the criteria. "Parent" is not correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check /vendor/craftcms/cms/src/models/FolderCriteria.php Class for reference. I guess most of craft's documentation lies in code.

Or you can visit https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-models-foldercriteria.html
which is the same thing.

check table "yourprefix_volumefolders" for data type of FolderCriteria.

Comment: Thank you very much, this document is I have been looking for.